# Forecasting based on relationship between time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have 2 timeseries datasets let's call them A and B. So my problem is I want to forecast future values of timeseries A based on timeseries B. Timeseries A and B have the same characteristics i.e most likely will follow the same trend and seasonality. An example is shown at this picture :

[image]

My question is what methods I could use so I can predict future values of timeseries A (blue line) based on timeseries B (orange line). I've been thinking about methods that could find the relationship between the 2 timeseries. In this picture timeseries B = 0,1 * timeseries A. But in a real case this relationship could be more complex.

So for a given future period let's say January to February I have values for timeseries B and I want to predict values from timeseries A for that same period. The reason for trying this approach is because I don't have actual values of the timeseries I want to predict but I do have very good forecasts of a very similar timeseries.

I am not sure what models I could use and to be more specific what the inputs of my model should be because this problem is not actually forecasting. It's more like about finding the relationship between timeseries.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment since I don't deem it as a full-fledged answer. First, you write that there's a linear correlation between A and B. By definition, an autoregressive model of order 1 for the process $Y_{t}$ can be written as $Y_{t} = \rho . y_{t-1}$, where $\rho$ is the lag-1 one correlation between them. If it's 0.1, it seems very low. Yet, correlation itself isn't a decisive factor in making predictions given that correlation (Pearson coefficient) measures linear correlation and some series might not be linear.

Comment: However, in your case, there's probably another term to the right side that expresses the uncertainty. Moreover, since you're trying to model B by using A, you need multivariate methods and you'll very likely have to "treat" your data before you work with it. I feel like the first step in time-series modeling tends to be finding out if you make your series stationary. But then again, the way you wrote about your series is kind of vague. It'd be better if you could present an example of your data if your attempts at modeling it. In my experience, that might get you more feedback.

Comment: Just to clarify my post a bit. The picture I posted and the relationship (=*0,1) between time series A and B  are just a random example. They are not actual data. I just wanted to show a visual representation of the general problem. The main idea is what models/methods can be used for such a case. No need to focus on these specific picture or data.